# Java: Graphics Disappear upon clicking JButton

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, jpanel

For my algorithms class we have to sort an array using mergesort and at each step draw the array as a histogram to graphically see what is going on. I am  running into a problem with the paintComponent method updating the array. When I run the program for the first time, it shows the jumbled array (as it should) and then when I click the mergesort button, I am expecting to see the sorted array but instead, I get nothing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Note: I know I'm not using mergesort now, I am just trying to get the graphics working first.

```
package a2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicalSort extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static int[] data = new int[200];
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Panel to hold graphical display of array
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton mButton = new JButton("Mergesort");

    int xPos = 0;
    static int barWidth = 8;
    static int barHeight = 1;

    public GraphicalSort() { 
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(mButton);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (int) (500 * Math.random() + 1);
        }
        setSize(barWidth * data.length, barHeight * 500 + buttonsPanel.getHeight());
        panel = new ArrayPanel();
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        repaint();
        validate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicalSort gs = new GraphicalSort();
        gs.setTitle("Graphical Sort");
        gs.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gs.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gs.setResizable(false);
        gs.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class ArrayPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                g.fillRect(xPos, (barHeight * 500) - (barHeight * data[i]), barWidth, barHeight * data[i]);
                xPos += barWidth;
            }   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        remove(panel);
        if (e.getSource() == mButton) {
            Arrays.sort(data);
            panel = new ArrayPanel();
    }
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        repaint();
        validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove/add the ArrayPanel like you are, you should be able to add it once and let the repaints take care of it

Comment: 1+ for posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't reseting the xPos instance variable which really should not be an instance variable because you only need it in the paintComponent.  So get rid of it and move it to the paintComponent() method.

You also don't need to remove and re-add the panel.  So here is what I did (note the removal of the statics!  Those should be instance variables):

```
int[] data = new int[200];
JPanel panel;
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
JButton mButton = new JButton("Mergesort");

int barWidth = 8;
int barHeight = 1;

class ArrayPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int xPos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Drawing " + i);
            g.fillRect(xPos, (barHeight * 500) - (barHeight * data[i]), barWidth, barHeight * data[i]);
            xPos += barWidth;
        }   
    }
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Arrays.sort(data);
    panel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much. This has been bugging me for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset your `xPos` variable, otherwise the x co-ordinate will appear off-screen:

```
int xPos = 0;
```

*Aside:* creating a new `ArrayPanel` is unnecessary — just resetting the variables and calling repaint will work by making `xPos` a class member variable of `ArrayPanel`.